# Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I rebooted my server yesterday, unfortunately mysql cannot be started now.

The error log is as following:

```
root@site-digger:/var/log/mysql# cat error.log 
130216 16:11:32 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130216 16:11:32  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130216 16:11:32  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130216 16:11:33  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 1382359817
130216 16:11:33 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address
130216 16:11:33 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
130216 16:11:33 [ERROR] Aborting

130216 16:11:33  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130216 16:11:38  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 1382359817
130216 16:11:38 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
...
```

I checked and didn't find any program is using 3306, please see following.

```
root@site-digger:/var/log/mysql# sudo netstat
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 site-digger.com:59367   li566-52.members.li:ssh ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 site-digger.com:ssh     61.150.56.248:65255     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    216 site-digger.com:ssh     61.150.56.248:61553     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 site-digger.com:www     1.82.9.18:55526         TIME_WAIT  
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    600880492 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     600845962 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     600845961 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     600596531 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     600596530
```

I tried sudo mysql start. But still not working.
OS: Ubuntu 11.10

The results for netstat -a -t is as following:

```
root@site-digger:/var/log/mysql# netstat -a -t
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:www                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:https                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0  20824 site-digger.com:59367   li566-52.members.li:ssh ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 site-digger.com:ssh     61.150.56.248:65255     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0     52 site-digger.com:ssh     61.150.56.248:61553     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 site-digger.com:www     crawl-66-249-73-2:45760 TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 site-digger.com:www     218.30.103.146:49094    TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

Comment: I know this is closed, but this is the top google result for this error message. I had this issue and discovered that during and upgrade rackspace had removed the 'lo' network interface (meaning that the ip addres 127.0.0.1 doesn't connect), this can be easily check by running 'ping 127.0.0.1' or running 'ifconfig' and checking for the lo localhost loopback network interface.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Port 33 **06**. not **60**. Netstat only shows active connections, not idle ones which are merely listening. You need `netstat -a -t` (to show only tcp ports).

Comment: Sorry, 3306. But it seems netstat -a -t still doesn't show 3306 port.

Comment: might show up as `:mysql` instead, or whatever's mapped to 3306 in /etc/services. `netstat -a -t -n` will show everything in numeric-form only. e.g. `netstat -a -t -n|grep 3306`.

Comment: sudo netstat -a -t -n|grep 3306 returns nothing.

Comment: what's the `bind-address` in your my.ini/my.cnf file?

Comment: bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

Comment: no idea, then. it's not running, has a valid bind address.\

Comment: Whoops. I just noticed ifconfig show "inet addr:127.0.0.2". I think you have found the reason.

Comment: well, yeah... that'd be a problem...

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys! It was exactly my problem! I have no idea why this question was downvoted.