# Mysql: Can´t start Server debian wheezy

Tags: mysql, sockets, debian, port

Everytime i try to start my mysql service i get the same error

Error message:

150130 15:56:31 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address
150130 15:56:31 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3305 ?
150130 15:56:31 [ERROR] Aborting

My Error log is empty

Conf file snippet:

[client] 
port        = 3305

socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]

user        = mysql

pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

port        = 3305

basedir     = /usr

datadir     = /var/lib/mysql

tmpdir      = /tmp

lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql

skip-external-locking

- Sorry for my bad english

[Complete Conf file](http://stroskler.de/my.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your port(3305) is occupied by another process.. you can :

1) switch to different port

2) kill/modify the process holding this port

(look it up using: 
    [lsof -i :3305](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/184/How_to_find_out_which_process_is_listening_upon_a_port)
)

in addition, this could be the cause of it (as one stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908430/cant-start-server-bind-on-tcp-ip-port-cannot-assign-requested-address)) :
Change bind-address to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

Skipping network worked for me :

```
# echo "skip-networking" >> /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Then start mysql again.